# Difference between describe-stacks and list-stacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I had a question in my Practice Certification and was unsure of the answer. I did check FAQ but I'm still a bit confused. I know the syntax of the two is like this:

```
describe-stacks --stack-name
list-stacks --stack-status-filter
```

However, if we don't provide `--stack-name` in case of the former, FAQ states it also "lists the set of stack instances" which is also the description of the second.

Are the two identical when `--stack-name` is not provided for `describe-stacks` thus the only difference is the `--stack-status-filter` for `list-stacks`?

Answer (score 2):

[`describe-stacks`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html) returns more information than [`list-stacks`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-stacks.html):

- Outputs
- Tags
- DisableRollback
- Capabilities

Basically, `list-stacks` should be used to retrieve a list of stacks for display or iteration. `describe-stacks` should be used when you want details of a specific stack(s).

Use whichever one best meets your needs.